# Is it possible to access a user's Google +1 (Plus One) history via an API?

Tags: google-plus-one

I would like to access a user's Google Plus One history

With +1 enabled, the history is saved in your Google profile and optionally can be displayed:

http://www.google.com/+1/button/

It is possible to access this programatically (once the user has given permission via normal Google Authentication and Authorization?)

I have only been able to find information for the API to add the button to sites.

Comment: Similar question being asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6207774/how-to-programmatically-retreive-the-total-number-of-google-1s-for-a-url/

Comment: Also, have you dug through this documentation? https://code.google.com/apis/+1button/

Answer (score 8):

You can allways try to parse the data used by G+ itself.

The G+ user profile has a tab with all public +1, that can be fetched with

`https://plus.google.com/_/plusone/get?oid=<google-plus-id>`

It seems to be related to JSON, but with some differences.

Comment: Wouldn't this only be useful for getting the likes of the currently logged in user?  How you would use this to get the likes of a third party user who has granted your site access to their profile?

Answer (score 4):

Check this out....

https://developers.google.com/+/history/

Comment: Awesome! I had given up on the project but it looks like this will do the trick (as soon as it's released from developer preview.)

Comment: Wow, looks like this is it! Good find (I thought it was never going to happen).

Answer (score 3):

Dave,
I'm not sure about a user's history, but the count for particular URL is available via a JSON-RPC service (https://clients6.google.com/rpc).  Here's a little post on how to:
  http://www.johndyer.name/post/Getting-Counts-Twitter-Links-Facebook-Likes-Shares-and-Google-Plus-One-Buttons.aspx

I'm guessing that same service can get additional data, but I can't find any public documentation either.